# Python scripts fail to run yet return no errors

Tags: python

I am on Windows with Python 3.7.2.
Whenever I run a code that is not within a forever loop, such as

```
print("hello world")
```

nothing happens. In IDLE, it just sits there and does not output anything. In command prompt, the Window closes as soon as I run it.
When I make a forever loop, such as

```
x = 0
while x == 0:
    print("hello world")
```

it works fine. At one point I was having problems with Python, so I reinstalled it.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps a call to `flush` is needed to flush the output?

Comment: If you actually open up 'cmd' and navigate to the location of the code and run it, will the command box close?

Comment: In command prompt, this is expected behavior. The string was printed and the program exits. This all happens very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Your script **IS** running. It just prints within a few milliseconds and then exits the prompt. You can see this if you adjust your script like such:

```
print("hello world")
input('press enter to end.') # will await user input
```

Or at least this would explain the command prompt issue I think. I'm not sure if this explains the IDLE error...we may need screenshots?